# centering fixed width elements with css

Tags: html, css

I've found two common ways of centering a fixed-width element horizontally with CSS, and I was hoping someone could help me more deeply understand when one might use one technique rather than the other.

One technique involves using `text-align:center` while the other involves `margin:auto`.

Below I've illustrated how both can be used to achieve the same thing. Looking at the code, it's tempting to say that the `margin:auto` method is better all-around, but I can't help but wonder if there are other better ways to do this sort of thing, or if there are cases for which the `text-align` method is preferable.

You can see the example code here: http://dabblet.com/gist/1634534 or below:

```
<div class="wrap1">
  <h1>Hey now</h1>
</div>

<div class="wrap2">
  <h1>Hey now</h1>
</div>
```

---

```
h1 {
    background-color: #CCC;
    width: 200px;
}

div.wrap1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 5px;
}
div.wrap1 h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

div.wrap2 {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
}

div.wrap2 h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is in the implementations.

Wrap1 uses `display: inline-block`. By making the element inline-block elements around it will be "inline" with it, meaning it will visually be displayed horizontally on the same plane.

Wrap2 uses `margin: 0 auto` and the display is the `default: block`. This of course makes the element a block element and therefore it will visually be displayed on it's on line.

The conclusion is if you want to center a bunch of inline objects, use `display: inline-block`. If you are centering a single block element, the `margin: 0 auto` solution works.

P.S. the `display: inline-block` solution also works for variable width elements

Edit: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9JZvq/1/) with your examples but edited to show variable width elements and multiple inline elements.

Comment: I like your mention of centering multiple inline-block elements since that's a case that I actually recently ran into. Still. using `text-align:center` on the container felt wrong. It seems that this case would be better served by wrapping the inline elements in a parent with `margin: 0 auto` ...hard to avoid "divitis", but I can't think of a better way.

Comment: NB: The aforementioned example involved fixed-width elements.

Answer (score 3):

The text-align CSS property is only to be used when you have text to move on your page.

If you want to center a div in your screen you should always use margin: auto. Semantically speaking and in practice, margin: auto is the one that everybody uses when it comes to center blocks.

So, if you want to place h1, use text-align (see the link below, they use text-align on a header block).

Edit: See this page for common practice: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Answer (score 2):

[**http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-align:**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-align)

> text-align specifies how the **inline content of a block** is aligned,
>   when the sum of the widths of the inline boxes is less than the width
>   of the line box.

[**http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/margins :**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/margins)

> Margin properties allow the author to control a box’s margin